# Обязательные поля формы

Tags: python, django

Доброго времени суток. Допустим есть такая форма:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Можно ли на бэкенде указать что обязательное поле или name или email, ну и при обоих заполненных полях форма тоже будет валидной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете определить свой [метод валидации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/)

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        clean_data = super(SomeForm, self).clean()
        name = clean_data.get('name')
        phone = clean_data.get('phone')
        if not (name or phone):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Необходимо указать имя или телефон!')
```